# Why is there such a large evening rise of temperature and night sweats in certain diseases like TB, lymphoma etc?

Tags: immunology, medicine

I've heard that it's got to do something with the levels of cortisol which usually dampens the effects of IL-1, but when it's night time the cortisol levels are usually low so IL-1 response is exaggerated.

But why does it occur to a greater extent in diseases like TB and lymphoma? Why is the interleukin 1 effect during night so much greater in these diseases than in case of other viral and bacterial infections?

Comment: Where are you getting the idea that temperature doesn't tend to increase at night with other illnesses?

Comment: @BryanKrause night sweats are a typical, and at times dramatic symptom characteristic (but not diagnostic) of TB, endocarditis, and certain cancers. I'm not aware of data on the how the mechanism is different from typical fever produced by IL-1 myself. I would say this is a good question.

Comment: Of note, there are other instances where fever has a periodicity to it. The quotidian fever of malaria comes to mind, but if I recall, that's associated with the life cycle of the parasite.

Comment: @DeNovo But isnt body temperature itself also circadian, with fevers from just about every cause following this cycle (exceptions being anything with an onset or resolution too fast to see it)?

Comment: @BryanKrause you're right, body temperature is circadian. I remember a 4th year medical student asking me if a regular increase in temperature by 0.5 C every night meant his patient might have malaria. It didn't. The difference is a matter of degree, but it's a significant degree. Drenching night sweats will make any good clinician immediately suspicious of some specific causes. As to the periodicity of fevers in malaria, the pattern is an increase of 3-4C at regular intervals (the specific interval depends on the species).

Comment: @DeNovo I don't doubt that malaria, TB, or lymphoma could have a particularly strong periodicity, but my understanding is that fever of all cause follows a circadian rhythm (again, excluding cases where pyrogen levels are either increasing so rapidly or dispersing quickly, in which case that time course would overwhelm a circadian rhythm, I'm referring to cases where fever is persisting on the order of at least days), whereas OP suggests that this is limited to TB and lymphoma, which seems to be a similar misconception shared by your med student.

Comment: OP, I've edited this question to focus on why the nightly increase in temperature is exaggerated in these particular disease (rather than why it occurs at all, since you seem to already have a handle on why it occurs in the general case). @BryanKrause I see your point. I've edited to make it a better question.

Comment: I beleive sweating is a sign of Fall in temperature and not Rise?? Am I wrong?

Comment: As for some parasitic infections like Wucheria, filarial worms were shed during night, so fever at night. In certain other conditions, temperature outside in daytime is already hot, so body does not need to rise core temperature to kill virus/org ,but need to do say at nights.